# Replacing items in a list in Django through a form

Tags: python, django, list

I have a python list with hundreds/thousands of strings:

```
['hello', 'good morning', 'evening everyone' ... ]
```

I loop through these items on a Django page and in some circumstances, I need to show an input to allow the user to change the string. It looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
{% for item in list %}

<p>{{ item }}</p>
{% if certain_condition %}
<input name="replace">
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</form>
```

The user may leave all fields empty, fill all of them out, or anything in between.

Now, when the form is posted, I need to create a new list (or replace the old list), in which those items that are sent in the POST are being replaced.

However, I'm not totally sure what the best way is to engineer this. I'd like clean and efficient code, but my first doubt is how to convey in the POST *which* of the items is being replaced. Should I add another input that contains the position of the original item in the list? Or should I send the original name? Or is there a better way?

To replace I'm thinking of using list comprehension, but also not sure if this is the best way. Any suggestions on how to best structure this would be most welcome.

---

Full example:

```
['hello', 'good morning', 'evening everyone', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6' ]
```

Let's say the user sees three POST fields, for the last three items, and only fills out the last two with the strings 'new-item5' and 'new-item6', then I want to somehow get to this list:

```
['hello', 'good morning', 'evening everyone', 'item4', 'new-item5', 'new-item6' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've done it in multiple ways in the past: sending either through the position in the list as well as sending through the previous value, and then looping through the list to find this, and it all works, but it doesn't feel right. So it's not really about how to make it work, but rather what kind of approach would be recommended here.

Comment: I read about trying to do things the 'pythonic' way but am new to python and in trying to get into good habits from the start.